# Set env variable in spock

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spock

I want to set the env variable for fileDirName but not sure how to add

In code:

```
@Value("${file.dir.name}")
private String fileDirName;
```

Test case:

```
def 'test file'() {
    when:
        def result = service.getFiles()
    then:
        result.success == Boolean.TRUE
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: file name must not be null.
```

How can I mock the env variable here

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the `env` of a java process once it is running. But since you are testing spring you don't have to.

Take a look at this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties) for more information. The easiest is to just use `@SpringBootTest`.

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "file.dir.name=/tmp" })
public class SpringBootPropertySourceResolverIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MyService service

    def 'test file'() {
        when:
        def result = service.getFiles()
        then:
        result.success == Boolean.TRUE
    }
}
```